# What are good security practices for a community site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security

How should I secure a community-driven site that I created in Rails? This site includes a microblogging service and I forum that I coded from scratch, plus it (obviously) includes user accounts. What are good security practices for a site like this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short abstract of what you should consider :

- Regarding **attacks on servers**

  - [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) are prevented by rails as long as you uses standard active query functions with has parameters. [All is described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection).
  - Mass Assignement vulnerabilities are less known but very important in rails as reminded [recently](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/GitHub-security-incident-highlights-Ruby-on-Rails-problem-1463207.html). Mass assignment allows creating or updating object from an hash (*Foobar.new(params[:foobar]* or *Foobar.update_attributes(params[:foobar]*). In this case, the user will be able to modify any value authorized for mass-assignment. Best practices includes disabling mass assignment by default (done with the last rails version) and not authorizing mass assignment for sensitive parameters (admin rights...)
- Regarding **attacks on clients**

  - Against [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS), always encode (with h function) when displaying parameters set by users. Be careful of not using single quote as delimiter as they are not encoded by rails.
  - Against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29), always uses the [CSRF token](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures) implemented in Rails

You can find helpful ressources here :

- [Rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#header-injection)
- [OWASP Cheatsheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets)
- [brakeman](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/) is a plugin which audit your rails code looking for vulnerabilities
- [Rails Best Practices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/) includes some security guidelines
- The [OWASP testing guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Project) is a good ressource for testing a website however remember that it is always better to have test by someone other than the developer.